# Is there a full XML specification with all possible fields for the Yodlee DAG?

Tags: yodlee, dummy-data

Is there was a full specification of all the account fields that can be used with the DAG?

Specifically, I'm looking to simulate a 401(k) account with limited options for investments, which may or may not have a balance in them.

Answer (score 0):

The default fields which appear when you create the DAG catalogue are all the fields which can be used. Here is an example of a 401 XML which you can upload to DAG investment and test it out.

```
<site>
 <status>0<status> 
  <investmentAccount accountBaseType="retirement" acctType="401k" uniqueId="47802637">
            <planNumber>25000</planNumber>
            <planName>GENERAL Potters PSP</planName>
            <accountName>GENERAL Potters PSP</accountName>
            <hasInvestmentOption>1</hasInvestmentOption>
            <accountNumber>13123534212</accountNumber>
            <balance balType="totalBalance">
              <curAmt curCode="USD">3588.65</curAmt>
            </balance>
            <holdingList>
              <holding holdingType="mutualFund" uniqueId="-633856231">
                <description>SSGA TRGT RET 2050 M SSGA TRGT RET 2050 M</description>
                <dailyChange curCode="USD">27.13</dailyChange>
                <price curCode="USD">10.449</price>
                <quantity>343.445</quantity>
                <value curCode="USD">3588.65</value>
                <cusipNumber>85744W655</cusipNumber>
              </holding>
            </holdingList>
           </investmentAccount>
        </site>
```